# Pycharm console: show() is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt4

I am using pycharm as the IDE for python development and I have noticed an annoying problem with the integrated python console. I use PyQt as the backbone for some GUI programming and when I make a window it does not show on the screen although I use the show() function. Here is an example code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from threading import Thread

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 50)
w.show()
```

Of course, if I run the same code in native python environment the window shows up right after the show() command.

I should add that I had the same problem with matplotlib figures in the same console and the the following code helped:

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

Is this a general problem with Pycharm console or the way it initiates the python console? and can someone please recommend a solution?

Here are some details about my os and IDE:
OS : Debian jessie
Python: Python 3.4
PyQt: PyQt4
Pycharm 2017.1.4

Comment: Some one posted a working solution here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000731850-show-is-not-working-in-the-console

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert, but your code does not work for me, it just flashes the window quickly. I'm on windows 10, python 3.6 and pyqt5 though. It does however stay if i initiate the event loop with `app.exec_()` afterwards.

Edit: I think i understand the issue at hand. To start, there's a difference between an interactive interpreter, like IDLE on windows and you native console, and a Pycharm file editor, which runs the script you make in a console.

In IDLE you can show and use code without an event loop, the exact specific reasons why it works, is a bit beyond me but it seems there is an event loop active there too(of some sort at least), since everything works as one would expect. That's a big difference compared to PyCharm!

In PyCharm you are only editing a python file, which you can run in the console. That means, that the only thing that gets run is whats in that file, and then it quits. And when it quits, everything is garbage collected and closed, and it's not waiting for your input. (Because unless you are using something like `input()` the code doesn't wait for anything, and it will go to the end.) That's why you usually use a event loop, to have to code wait for the user to finish using the GUI application, and then stop when the user is done. (Closes the GUI for example.) The big takeaway is, you can't write more code when you run a python file, and it will always end when you get to the end. So as soon as you `show()` your window, it'll be closed as the code is done and quits. So anything that's done, must be done before starting the event loop, and then closing that before doing something else, unless you trigger something with a button in the GUI for example, or run a thread in parallel that fixes stuff for you.

To compare that with matplotlib, you got the same issue. In matplotlib, the code waits for the user to close the graph window before it continues to the next piece of code. Unless you do something like `show(block=False)`, which spawns the graph in another thread or something of that sort, which circumvents this. (And as far as i know, PyQt does not support being in a thread, though you can run other pieces of code in another thread, but the GUI needs to be on the main one, because there is funky things that happen otherwise apparently. I'm not entirely sure on this one, since PyQt comes with it's own QThread, but i don't know it's limitations when it comes to the GUI.)

It's a long answer and it makes sense, ask and i'll try to clarify.

Comment: Did you try it directly in python? for me it works fine in native python but not in PyCharm console.

Comment: Tested both a python file and in PyCharm. I don't know enough to chalk it up to differences in the OSes, but did you try adding  an event loop? You can't interact with a GUI otherwise, unless you throw it up as a process that runs on its own.

Comment: With the event loop you probably mean the following command:
`app.exec_()`

Comment: Yes, this code starts the loop which allows for user interaction after setting up the GUI. Unless thats there, the code should have finished and the program closed instantly, as it happened in my test.

Comment: With the event loop you probably mean the following command:
`app.exec_()`. This should not be necessary for the operation of the GUI. I dont like to start the loop as it blocks the command line. I am after a GUI which at the same time allows me to access the command line. In the native python console, I can get the GUI running using the code in the original post without the `app.exec_()`, so it has to be possible to get it with the integrated console as well.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation, which should hopefully be correct or at least make sense.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer, however, I am not convinced this is the issue. I can just copy past the code to PyCharm console, so that the porgram dose not exit at the end of the file, or put a wait command, and in both cases the window dose not show, although the console dose not exit and I can still run new commands!